# Using ffmpeg to watermark a capturing video on Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm now researching on a project which utilizes ffmpeg to watermark captured video on Android. At the moment I can capture a video from the camera firstly and then use ffmpeg to watermark it. I don't know if it is possible to operate the video while it is being captured?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, how to capture a webcam video on my Windows system and draw a counting timestamp.

To list all devices that can be used as input :

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

To use my webcam as input and draw the timestamp (with `-t 00:01:00` 1 minute is recorded):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="1.3M HD WebCam" -t 00:01:00 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -an -y output.mp4
```

The font-file `Arial.ttf` was located in the folder I was with the terminal in.

(Source : http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20capture%20a%20webcam%20input and http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide)

I hope it may help.

Have a nice day ;)

Comment: I think it may not help in my case since I use the system app Camera to capture video rather than ffmpeg. Anyway, thank you all the same!

Comment: @shhp: can you share how you are able to watermark the video after capture. I am stuck in same situation using FFMPEG cannot apply watermark on captured video.

Comment: @Wikki you can see my answer to this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204092/how-to-execute-command-line-ffmpeg-commands-programatically-in-android/18205578#18205578)